# Перемещение блоков и фиксация столкновения

Tags: wpf

Нужно написать приложение, реализующее графические счеты: по горизонтальной линии мышью можно перемещать графический блок, при столкновении с другим блоком, они должны двигаться вместе. Как переместить мышью отдельный блок я представляю, но вот как фиксировать столкновение и передать движение другому блоку, у меня понимания нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ВПФ, а простая логика. Этапы алгоритма такие:

1. При движении блока нужно определить предельные значения его перемещения.
2. Нужно написать две похожие функции, которые будут сдвигать соседние блоки в случае их соприкосновения
3. При перемещении в одну сторону нужно сделать цикл `for` для одной или другой стороны блоков, в котором и применить созданные функции.